# Excel VBA - Array Formula Ignoring If Statement

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

I'm really new to array formulas. The flow should be IF the list has NO data entered in the array or only 1 entry, it shows "Add Weight" [7 total spots). Once two pieces of any data has been input anywhere in the array, it checks for the FIRST value in the array and subtracts the LAST value in the array.

This issue I'm getting is the cell shows #value when the array is empty instead of showing "Add Weight". The formula works perfectly once data is input and correctly subtracts the last entry from first entry regardless of their placement within the array.

This looks up the last entry in the array.

```
LOOKUP(2,1/(1-ISBLANK(D13:D19)),D13:D19))
```

This looks up the first entry in the array.

```
INDEX(D13:D19,(MATCH(FALSE,ISBLANK(D13:D19),0)))
```

Is it because the formula is marked as an array?

```
=IF(COUNTIF(DailyProgress[Change],"")>6,"Add Weight",LOOKUP(2,1/(1-ISBLANK(D13:D19)),D13:D19))-INDEX(D13:D19,(MATCH(FALSE,ISBLANK(D13:D19),0)))
```

If there is a better way to write this, I'm all ears.

EDIT:

In an adjacent column I have it showing the change from the previous cell like so:

```
=IF([@[Weight (lbs)]]="","",[@[Weight (lbs)]]-D17)
```

Where `D17` is the cell above the current row [This would be entered on row 18].

As it is, if the cell right above the adjacent cell is empty it shows it as zero and does "0 - value= -value" so with the change we just did I want it to compare it to the LAST input cell before it instead of the cell directly above it. I know this will need to be rewritten completely. Still using the `D13:D19` array.

Comment: 1. ISBLANK will return false if the cell has a formula even if that formula is returning `""`. 2. Did you enter it with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

Comment: The list for the array are all empty and without formulas. I also am doing CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER

Comment: maybe post some test data and expected outcome.

Comment: @ScottCraner Just added what I'm experiencing, I realized I missed the error I'm receiving

Answer (score 1):

Use this array formula:

```
=IFERROR(IF(MATCH(FALSE,D13:D19="",0)=MATCH(1E+99,D13:D19),"Add Weight",INDEX(D13:D19,MATCH(1E+99,D13:D19))-INDEX(D13:D19,MATCH(FALSE,D13:D19="",0))),"Add Weight")
```

Until there are at least two entries in D13:D19 it will Return `Add Weight`

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

---

FWIW:

The reason your COUNTIF did not work is the criteria, Change the `""` to `"="` and it would count the blanks:

```
COUNTIF(DailyProgress[Change],"=")>6
```

Comment: You're a legend. This worked perfectly. So I can understand this a little more, we use the 1E+99 because we're dealing with integers? How does this value get determined? Sorry for the annoying questions.

Comment: @BetaOp9 yes with numbers `1E+99` if it were text then it would be `"ZZZ"` to get the last cell.  Also just realized why your COUNTIF did not work.  I will add that to the answer.

Comment: That explains why the countif wasn't working. So with this change comes another question I put into the original question. Any insight?

Comment: That is a new question that deserves a new post.

Comment: Fair enough! I have to wait 90 minutes to make a new post it seems.

Comment: Scott: I reasked the question if you have a moment to check it out.

http://stackoverflow.com/q/42519376/7510470